# Importing Bing Maps into application using ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, bing-maps

I'd like to create an application using ArcGIS Engine 10.

I want to import Bing Maps into my application as base map. I surf the internet but couldn't find any tools or API to import these maps to my application.

Is there any way to import the maps to application using ArcGIS Engine?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the [Bing layer package](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b6969de2b84d441692f5bb8792e65d1f)?  There have been [changes in the licensing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/04/12/bing-maps-use-in-arcmap-has-changed/), so it wouldn't surprise me if this is broken.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is you now need a key from Microsoft to complete this task.

Here is the link to [request a key](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm#ESRI_QUESTIONANSWERS_2B2E612E1D294CE889AD1B3AD402F43B) and explanation on how it works once you get the key, it includes instructions for online use.

You need to install an update as well. The link to this is above as well.

Comment: This would be an answer to "How to license Bing Maps for ArcGIS Engine?" but the question is "Is there any way to import the maps to application using ArcGIS Engine?"

Comment: You cannot import them until you license them!  Additionally the user states they would like to create an application with... and this indicates they are at a start point. Surely step one is the license. One last item, that the link I provided does indeed go into detail on how to import the data.